# Format double with at least one decimal in printf

Tags: c, json, formatting, printf

To format a double for JSON with maximal precision but no trailing zero's we use `%.15g`. However in order to distinguish between integers and real numbers we want to format doubles with at least one digit, i.e. `"%.1f"`, except for numbers in scientific notation (which are doubles by definition).

Is there a way to implement this in a single snprint `format`?

```
double val;
char buf[32];

if(fabs(val) < 1e15 && !fmod(val, 1)){
  // whole numbers get at least one decimal
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%.1f", val);
} else {
  // automatically detemines decimal or scientific notation
  snprintf(buf, 32, "%.15g", val);
}
```

Comment: Using `15` to form "maximal precision" is in an correct assumption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use conversion specifier `g`, and add `.0` at the end of string, if string contains only sign and digit characters. The `yajl` library has an [example implementation](https://github.com/lloyd/yajl/blob/2.1.0/src/yajl_gen.c#L225-L228):

```
char buf[32];
sprintf(buf, "%.20g", val);
if (strspn(buf, "0123456789-") == strlen(buf)) {
  strcat(buf, ".0");
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using `fmod` is unreliable because `val` might not be a whole number, yet get printed as a whole number due to rounding, e.g. `1.0000000000001` when we limit json numbers to 8 digits.